# adding the feedparser module to python

Tags: python, netbeans, feedparser

I recently downloaded and installed feedparser with python,
I tried to run it but Netbeans shouts on import:
ImportError: No module named feedparser

restarted the Netbeans, still no go.

Comment: can you import it in a python shell?

Comment: Yes, and in fact when I open Netbeans>Window>PythonConsole
and try to import feedparser
I get http://pastebin.com/fwcbauNt

Comment: so to clarify, you can import it in the python shell with no errors, and just not in Netbeans?

Comment: Problem solved, turns out Netbeans uses Jython by default after you install the Python plugin, strange but fixable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans by default uses Jython, 
if you go to Tools>Python Platforms and see that Jython is the default. 
Switch it to Python and so the installed libraries would work. 
If you already have a project, you should right click on it, 
choose Python and on the platform choose Python instead of Jython.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to include the install path of feedparser.  Just a guess, but this has fixed this issue in the past for me.

Comment: I read the linked segment, didn't understand what I had to do (using linux btw)